# Attach an already existing article(or even a solution) to a case in Salesforce

Tags: case, knowledge, articles, console

During the process of closing an open case, instead of creating a new article and attaching it to a case. I want to attach an already existing article/or solution. I went through the http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_find_articles.htm&language=en_US link. But I am not getting options to attach an article to a Case by searching on it.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at a case, you should be able to see a Solutions section (subject to page layout for the case - if you don't see it, you will need to add it to the page layout for the case).

The solutions section has a "View Suggested Solutions" button which tries to match the case contents up with an existing solution. It also has a search box to allow you to search for keywords in existing solutions, which is more commonly how we use it. This provides a list of solutions, and clicking Select at the left of the appropriate solution will associate it with the case.